# Sqlite comparison between two date

Tags: sqlite, date, between

I hava a table with column date as TEXT with is format dd-MM-YYYY.
I try this query for select record:
SELECT * FROM fattureClienti WHERE data '16-06-2016'  BETWEEN '17-06-2016'
but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You used "Text" as your data type change it to date and try. One hack is use data type as "int" and store values as yyyyMMdd. Then it will very easy to get the result. For example 20160718 between 20160715 will give 20160716(yyyyMMdd)and 20160717.